# Removing repeated values in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am using a foreach loop to display array values in table. Below is how my table looks like.

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <th>Model</th>
       <th>Trim</th>
       <th>Year</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>Impreza</td>
       <td>GC</td>
       <td>1994</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Impreza</td>
       <td>GC</td>
       <td>1995</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Impreza</td>
       <td>GC</td>
       <td>1996</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Impreza</td>
       <td>GC-Turbo</td>
       <td>1994</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Impreza</td>
       <td>GC-Turbo</td>
       <td>1995</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I manipulate the array remove the repetition from the table or simplify it?

Array Values:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMPREZA
            [1] => GC
            [2] => 1994
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMPREZA
            [1] => GC
            [2] => 1995
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMPREZA
            [1] => GC
            [2] => 1996
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMPREZA
            [1] => GC-TURBO
            [2] => 1994
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMPREZA
            [1] => GC-TURBO
            [2] => 1995
        )

)
```

Displaying array values in table

```
<table>
 <thead></thead>
 <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($options as $option) : ?>
     <tr>
        <?php foreach ($option as $value) : ?>
          <td><?= $value ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like the table to be like this: How would I go about it? Please am not advanced in PHP.

```
<table>
 <thead>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Trim</th>
    <th>Year</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Impreza</td>
    <td>GC</td>
    <td>1994-1996</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Impreza</td>
    <td>GC-Turbo</td>
    <td>1994-1995</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have table value in array or just have static values?

Comment: Yes I do. I have edited my question to include it. Please check

Comment: @SamN Is this coming from database? If yes, show your SQL query and table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you could use a compound key for the `Model` and `Trim` and gather the `Year` in an array.

To get the result use a [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) in combination with [min](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [max](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and explode by a dash to keep only a single year in the result if there is only 1 year.

For example:

```
    $options = [
    ['IMPREZA', 'GC', 1994],
    ['IMPREZA', 'GC', 1995],
    ['IMPREZA', 'GC', 1996],
    ['IMPREZA', 'GC-TURBO', 1994],
    ['IMPREZA', 'GC-TURBO', 1995],
    ['IMPREZA', 'Test', 1998]
];

$result = [];

foreach ($options as $option) {
    $compoundKey = $option[0] . "|" . $option[1];
    isset($result[$compoundKey]) ? $result[$compoundKey][] = $option[2] : $result[$compoundKey] = [$option[2]];
}

foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $parts = explode('|', $key);
    $parts[] = implode("-", array_unique([min($value), max($value)]));
    $result[$key] = $parts;
}
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [IMPREZA|GC] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMPREZA
            [1] => GC
            [2] => 1994-1996
        )

    [IMPREZA|GC-TURBO] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMPREZA
            [1] => GC-TURBO
            [2] => 1994-1995
        )

    [IMPREZA|Test] => Array
        (
            [0] => IMPREZA
            [1] => Test
            [2] => 1998
        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/e5Fof)

If you want to reset the keys, you could use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) like  `array_values($result)`

Answer (score 1):

My way seems little bit **longer** but this array result will help you to build your table easily for sure.

```
$result = $expected_array = [];
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $result[$v[0].'#'.$v[1]][] = $v[2]; //making unique key value with # for year
}

foreach($result as $key=>$value){
    list($model,$trim) = explode('#',$key); // exploding with # to get model and trim
    $expected_array[]= ['Model'=>$model, 'Trim'=>$trim,'Year'=>implode('-',[$value[0],$value[count($value)-1]])];
}
print_r($expected_array);
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/fXZjQ